# npm installed in project how to use them

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-ui-bootstrap

Created a project in web directory. Hello world example works.

Installed node and grunt.

Ran:
      npm install angular-ui-bootstrap --save-dev

angular-ui-bootstrap is now in node_modules

How do I start developing with any npm installed local package?

Like this?

```
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

My point of installing is because I am following tutorials and they have this:

```
 var app = angular.module('store', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Which I believe needs ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Thanks!

Comment: yes, except that you shouldn't install angular-ui-bootstrap with `--save-dev`, since it's a dependency you will be using in production. Instead, it should be `--save`

Comment: Ok thanks Tom.  Should I run the same thing again then and remove -dev?  Or will that mess things up?

Comment: If you're not using bundler (webpack, etc.), then yeah, add everything as a script tag to your main HTML entry page to the app.

Comment: This is a broad follow up question, but since I am referencing a local directory for development.  What does one typically do when they are ready for production?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add

```html
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

in index.html, only then you can inject 'ui.bootstrap' into your angular module else you'll get injector error.